# Errors installing Ubuntu / No graphics / ISO burnt to a partition / Grub4Dos

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb-installation, grub4dos

I'm trying to install ubuntu from a 4Gb partition I created (virtual USB). It is supposed to work as an external USB stick. I have done that before, several times, using this same machine. But for some reason I'm no longer able to repeat the process.

**First problem:** No matter how hard I try, I cannot get the machine to boot directly from the virtual USB. I put the boot flag to that partition. It doesn't work. I used a **Grub4Dos** menu to point to that partition (the ubuntu install), it starts in text mode and never reach the graphic installation, It shows long lines telling what's going on and at some point it completely stops. In the latter lines I see some errors referring files or paths not found. It shouldn't happen, everything is there.

**What's happening now?**

1. Same machine.
2. Same configuration in the machine setup (almost sure / I tried also default setup).
3. Same ISO file (no doubts here).
4. I made some changes in the partitions, but that shouldn't be the problem (Nonetheless I tried to rollback most of the changes).

I'm stuck here. A solution may be to buy a USB stick, a problem I had already overcome.

Answer (score 0):

**I ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION:**

Finally I was able, again, to install ubuntu from an ISO burnt to a 4GB partition in the same disc. Two things I did different and I'm not sure which made the day:

1. I added a **lba** flag to the boot flag.
2. I placed the 4GB partition as the first partition, erased the Boot4DOS Files (grldr, menu.lst, menu-advanced.lst).

I was able to correctly launch the ubuntu installation directly from that partition. Indirect reference from a grub does not seem to work.